# UICollectionView when inserting an item, the ui stuck for a second

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have collectionView with Flow layout (ZJFlexibleLayout)
When I scroll down and reach the middle of the collectionView, I bring data from api for next page, when I want to add this data to the end of the collectionView by the next line:

collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)

the ui is freeze for 1 second, make the scrolling to be not smooth.

I saw other apps succeed getting smooth scroll with paging.
Any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: Add data asynchronously. Or show the code where you are adding and how you are adding.

Comment: Maybe you have too heavy init's in classes you're adding. Freezing means that your program doing something in main thread for a second. You can also try to profile your project by Instruments -> Time profiler, there are lots of tutorials in internet

Comment: Please add the code where you are adding images, might be your are not using background tread to download the images.